# How to set image quality for writer_png_Export using libreoffice's storeToURL?

Tags: libreoffice

With XStorable's interface storeToURL, I can export a document as an png file with filter: writer_png_Export. My propertyValue is:

```
PropertyValue[] pngWriterPropertyValues = new PropertyValue[2];
pngWriterPropertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue();
pngWriterPropertyValues[0].Name = "Overwrite";
pngWriterPropertyValues[0].Value = new Boolean(true);
pngWriterPropertyValues[1] = new PropertyValue();
pngWriterPropertyValues[1].Name = "FilterName";
pngWriterPropertyValues[1].Value = "writer_png_Export";
```

The problem is that the generated image is blurred. Is there a property that I can control the resolution of the image to improve its quality?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: add a property called FilterData and set according values. Sample code:

```
PropertyValue[] pngWriterPropertyValues = new PropertyValue[3];
pngWriterPropertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue();
pngWriterPropertyValues[0].Name = "Overwrite";
pngWriterPropertyValues[0].Value = new Boolean(true);
pngWriterPropertyValues[1] = new PropertyValue();
pngWriterPropertyValues[1].Name = "FilterName";
pngWriterPropertyValues[1].Value = "writer_png_Export";
PropertyValue pngFilterData[] = new PropertyValue[2];
pngFilterData[0] = new PropertyValue();
pngFilterData[0].Name = "PixelWidth";
pngFilterData[0].Value = 1654;
pngFilterData[1] = new PropertyValue();
pngFilterData[1].Name = "PixelHeight";
pngFilterData[1].Value = 2338;
pngWriterPropertyValues[2] = new PropertyValue();
pngWriterPropertyValues[2].Name = "FilterData";
pngWriterPropertyValues[2].Value = pngFilterData;
```